# MySQL query to calculate the time taken for a person to work on a ticket

Tags: mysql, select, join

i'm very new to this portal.
Please pardon if my question seems to be not perfect.

I have two tables A and B with 1:n relation with id as the foreign key.
B table captures the history when ever the ticket is updated.

I'm looking to write a query for an expected result as below:

Ticket-ID(A)   Ticket Name(A) **Time Taken(B)**
5              ABCD           difference between(time when ticket is closed - time when ticket is open)

Probably looking for difference of time from two entries in the B table with the same foreign key from the A table

I've tried joins, but looking for a more optimized query for this.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could use subqueries instead of joins. First goal should be the right answer. If you got it by more than one way use MySQLs `EXPLAIN` to find out which one's more performant.

Comment: Are there SLAs attached to these times?  Would it be important to consider a clock may run from 0600 to 1800, then stops at 1800 and doesn't resume until 0600 the next morning?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be able to make the calculation for your earliest and latest updates for a given ticket. THe fields names are assumed, but should give you the idea.

```
SELECT
    a.ticket_id AS ticket_id,
    MIN(b.update_timestamp) AS first_update,
    MAX(b.update_timestamp) AS last_update,
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
WHERE a.ticket_id = ?
GROUP BY a.ticket_id
```